# Python datetime timestamp issue

Tags: python

I was trying to create a dictionary with time stamp as the key.
the code is :

```
    >>> stamp = datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 12, 12, 26, int('13'))
    >>> new_dict = {}
    >>> new_dict[stamp] = 'one'
    >>> print new_dict
    {datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 12, 12, 26, 13): 'one'}
    >>> print stamp
    2012-04-12 12:26:13
```

Why does it not take the key as '2012-04-12 12:26:13' and instead taking the expression 'datetime.datetime()' as the key?

Answer (score 2):

Because `stamp` is a `datetime.datetime` object. When you `print` it, a string representing this object is printed. If you want a `str` key, try

```
new_dict[str(stamp)] = 'one'
```

Answer (score 2):

'2012-04-12 12:26:13' is a string, and `stamp` in your example is a `datetime.datetime` object.

You can use datetime objects directly as keys in a dictionnary, as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) (two identical datetimes will have the same hash).

Comment: can i use it like: new_dict[datetime.datetime()] ?